# Suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $f : X \to X$ is a bijection (that is, one to one and onto) satisfying $f(x) > x$ for all $x \in X$

Tags: functions

Suppose $X$ is a subset of real numbers and $f: X \to X$ is a bijection  satisfying  $f(x) > x$ for all $x$ belonging to $X$.  Then $X$ cannot be:

(A) the set of integers

(B) the set of positive integers

(C) the set of positive real numbers

(D) the set of real numbers

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Have you tried constructing such a function $f$ for the various sets $X$?

Comment: $(B)$ the set of positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is B). $f(n)>n\geq 1$ for all $n$ so $1$ is not the image of any number.
To rule out other options consider $f(x)=x+1$ for A) and D) and $f(x)=2x$ for C).